# Change Color of Text Field from Text Field in Material UI v5

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield, background-color

I am Using MUI and did everything to change the Color of the Text in a MUI Text Field and/or its background Color.

I followed the Documentation and tried:

```
const CssTextField = styled(TextField)({
```

And also Things inside the Component, such as

```
InputProps={{
           style: { color: "red" }
           }}
```

or

```
InputProps={{
            color: "red"
           }}
```

Nothing works for me and I don´t know why.

I hope that you can help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [docs](https://mui.com/api/text-field/), `InputProps` accepts:

> Props applied to the Input element. It will be a FilledInput, OutlinedInput or Input component depending on the variant prop value.

Therefore, `style: { color: "red" }` doesn't work because the aforementioned components don't accept the `style` prop and `color` prop accepts theme colors such as `secondary` , `error` etc.

You can customize the color and background of your `TextField` with  [sx prop](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/#main-content):

```
      <TextField
        id="outlined-basic"
        variant="outlined"
        sx={{
          input: {
            color: "red",
            background: "green"
          }
        }}
      />
```

Comment: Yeah that kind of works :). I edited your Code like this and then It works Perfekt.
sx={{
  background: "#FFFFFF",
   input:{
    color: "red",
  }
}}

Comment: How would you change the focus color here? So that focus and not focussed are two different colors?

Comment: @kabooya Select the focus class and target the properties you need:
`
sx={{
          "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
            "&.Mui-focused fieldset": {
              borderColor: "green",
            },
          },
        }}
`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
InputProps={{
        backgroundColor: "red"
       }}
```

instead of

```
InputProps={{
        color: "red"
       }}
```

Comment: Doesn´t do anything different :( Still remains the standard Color

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```js
// Option 1
<TextField style ={{width: '100%'}} />

// Option 2
<TextField fullWidth />
```

Comment: Yeah that works, but the width is not the Problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try with these properties, add `.MuiInputLabel-root` and `.MuiOutlinedInput-input` as well.

As Mui documentation says you can create styled text field with these properties:

```
const WhiteTextField = styled(TextField)({
    '& label.Mui-focused': {
      color: 'white',
    },
    '& .MuiInput-underline:after': {
      borderBottomColor: 'white',
    },
    '& .MuiInputLabel-root': {
      color: 'white',
    },
    '& .MuiOutlinedInput-input': {
      color: 'white',
    },
    '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
      '& fieldset': {
        borderColor: 'white',
      },
      '&:hover fieldset': {
        borderColor: 'white',
      },
      '&.Mui-focused fieldset': {
        borderColor: 'white',
      },
    },
  });
```

and later you can use

```
<CssTextField label="*" name="*" variant="outlined" size="small" />
```